# Strange use of greater than operator in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Can anyone shed any light on this short JavaScript line of code? Not sure what it is doing, as the greater than symbol inside it seems counter-intuitive:

```
direction = currentImage > imageToGo ? 1 : -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If `currentImage` is greater than `imageToGo`, direction is assigned 1. If not, it is assigned -1.

Check out [ternary operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

Answer (score 0):

It is shorthand for **if-else** condition or basically [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) operator.

So your code can be written as

```
if(currentImage > imageToGo){
   direction = 1;
}
else{
   direction = -1
}
```